# Immutable borrow might be used here, when `guard` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `RwLockWriteGuard`

Tags: rust

Ho do i change the value of a borrowed mutable reference after it is also borrowed immutably inside the same scope?, in my case the part borrowed immutably is wrapped inside `Arc<RwLock<T>>`

the actual snippet i'm having trouble with:

```rust
Event::RedrawRequested(_) => {
    let mut guard = app.write().unwrap();
    let guard = &mut *guard;

    // (...)

    app.camera_controller.as_mut().unwrap().update_camera(app.camera.as_mut().unwrap(), dt);
    dt = frame_start.elapsed();
}
```

I have a minimal example of my issue:

```rust
use std::{
    ops::Deref,
    sync::{Arc, RwLock},
};

struct Inner {
    inner_number: Option<f32>,
}

struct App {
    inner: Arc<RwLock<Inner>>,
    outer_number: Option<f32>,
}

impl App {
    fn new(inner_number: f32, outer_number: f32) -> Self {
        Self {
            inner: Arc::new(RwLock::new(Inner {
                inner_number: Some(inner_number),
            })),
            outer_number: Some(outer_number),
        }
    }
}

impl Deref for App {
    type Target = Arc<RwLock<Inner>>;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.inner
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut app = App::new(10.0, 20.0);

    {
        let mut guard = app.write().unwrap();
        let guard = &mut *guard;

        guard.inner_number = Some(guard.inner_number.unwrap() + 5.0);

        *(app.outer_number.as_mut().unwrap()) *= 2.0;
    }

    println!("{:?}", app.outer_number);
}
```

error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `app.outer_number` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:42:11
   |
37 |         let mut guard = app.write().unwrap();
   |                         ----------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
42 |         *(app.outer_number.as_mut().unwrap()) *= 2.0;
   |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
43 |     }
   |     - immutable borrow might be used here, when `guard` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `RwLockWriteGuard`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=935e70d66af8343b19aea4a0f280a27a.

Comment: A minimal example is good, but an explanation is also necessary most of the times, even if we can understand the problem without it. Help us help you.

Comment: And also, please include the **full** error message in the **body** of the question.

Comment: Well, the compiler is explaining the problem clearly. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `Ho do i change the value of a borrowed mutable reference after it is also borrowed immutably inside the same scope?` - That by definition is incorrect, a variable can never be borrowed mutably and immutably at the same time. It can be *either* borrowed mutably *once* or borrowed immutably *many times*, but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I found so far to get your code to compile.

### Solution #1:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut app = App::new(10.0, 20.0);

    {
        {
            let mut guard = app.write().unwrap();
            let guard = &mut *guard;

            guard.inner_number = Some(guard.inner_number.unwrap() + 5.0);
            // Drop guard here, which will release the `app` borrow
        }

        *(app.outer_number.as_mut().unwrap()) *= 2.0;
    }

    println!("{:?}", app.outer_number);
}
```

This one works because `guard` gets dropped before the `*= 2.0`. `app`
cannot be mutably borrowed once in `guard` and once immutably during the `*= 2.0`. Objects can never be borrowed mutably and immutably at the same time. Wrapping the entire `guard` section in its own context ensures that `guard` is released before the `*= 2.0` section.

### Solution #2:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut app = App::new(10.0, 20.0);

    {
        // Use app.inner.write instead of app.write
        let mut guard = app.inner.write().unwrap();
        let guard = &mut *guard;

        guard.inner_number = Some(guard.inner_number.unwrap() + 5.0);

        *(app.outer_number.as_mut().unwrap()) *= 2.0;
    }

    println!("{:?}", app.outer_number);
}
```

This one works because `guard` doesn't actually hold the entire `app` as reference, but just the `app.inner` member. As the `*= 2.0` section only references `app.outer_number`, it doesn't complain as those two sections don't actually borrow the same object.